# React production using react-app-rewired nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, react-router-v4, antd

I have tried to deploy my app on heroku and it work normally. But when I build my app using react-app-rewired script and deploy it to my server using nginx. When access my app, it still work fine but if I reload page with contextPath: http://35.240.229.243/products it throws 404 error. You can access my app in http://35.240.229.243 to test. I am using react-router with history. Help me thanks

Comment: Can you show your nginx conf file

Comment: I dont use any conf. I just throw build folder to /usr/share/nginx/html

Comment: u have to use .htaccess file

Comment: @Asifvora can you tell me about this file? thanks so much

Comment: Please refer here http://www.htaccess-guide.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find default nginx conf file and disable it, by default it will be under `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

and create new file under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`

```
sudo touch /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default/redbox
```

and use vim or nano to put this text into new conf file `redbox`,

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

and enable it

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/redbox /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/redbox
```

next, make sure that there are no syntax errors in Nginx files,

```
sudo nginx -t
```

If no problems were found, restart Nginx.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: Thanks. I already make it work correctly with `location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}`